# How to add a db_datareader to a secondary in SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, authentication

We have a SQL Azure database configured with an online secondary. I would like to configure a user/login on the secondary to support a reporting workload. To do this, I have done the following:

- Created a login on both servers with the same name
- Created a user in the database on the primary server, linked to the login
- Verified that the user has been replicated to the secondary
- Confirmed successful connectivity to the primary database using the login using Management Studio and specifying the correct database (not master)
- Confirmed FAILED connectivity to the secondary database using the login using Management Studio and specifying the correct database (not master)

Each time I attempt to connect to the second with the login, I get the message "Cannot open the database master". I suspect that the issue is that the SID for the login created on the secondary does not match the SID on the primary, and thus the user on the secondary is not linked to that login. I have attempted to remedy this with the following:

```
ALTER USER [myuser] WITH LOGIN=[mylogin]
```

However, I receive the message "Failed to update database [mydatabase] because the database is the secondary database". I've attempted running this on the primary, which succeeds, but does not have the cascading effect on the secondary that I'm hoping for.

In short, how to I add allow access to the secondary database?

Comment: I have a temporary solution, which is to create the user in the master database on the secondary. This allows me to connect in management studio. I would note that specifying "mydatabase" in the "Connect to Database" field in the connection dialog box is diregarded and I'm still connected to the master when it succeeds. This step was not necessary on the primary.

Comment: The login on each server has to have a matching SID. So you need to re-create the login on the secondary and this time explicitly give it the same SID as the primary. [I talk about this here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81849/managing-logins-with-availabilty-groups/81858#81858).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the reply. I was able to recreate the login such that the SID's match. From, there, I was able to drop the user, recreate it, and add it to the db_datareader on the primary and this flowed correctly over to the secondary, enabling connectivity. Thanks suggestion - I hadn't realized you can specify the SID when you run CREATE LOGIN.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run the "CREATE LOGIN mylogin WITH SID={the sid from the primary}", then recreate the database user and grant the appropriate roles via sp_addrolemember. Once the SID's for the logins match, everything functions as expected. Thanks to @AaronBertrand for the tip!